# Custom tableview cells issue

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm having problems with custom cells in a tableView. What I am doing is, I access my Database and for every row in the Database, I will fill one cell. The problem is, it only prints the last row over and over for each cell; Then, I tried using the filter (by ID), but it only prints the first row for every cell. 
I thank in advance for your help. My code is the following

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
var x = Int()
    do{
    let count = try conn.db!.scalar(tblPersona.count)
    x = count
    }
    catch{
    }
    return x
}



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! consultaInformacionTableViewCell
    var res = Int64 (1)
    do{

        let query = tblPersona.filter(id == res)
        for custom in try conn.db!.prepare(query){
            print(custom[nombre]!)

            cell.nombreLabel.text = custom[nombre]!
            cell.emailLabel.text = custom[email]!
            res = res + 1
        }
    }
    catch{

    }
    return cell
}
```

When I print "custom[nombre]!" it prints all the rows each time one loop is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter criteria appears to be incorrect.

```
tblPersona.filter(id == res)
```

The comparison is resolving first. So, you are effectively saying:

```
tblPersona.filter(true)
```

It appears that "true" is returning every entry. However, without knowing about the type of filter you're using, I can't provide a working example.

Comment: Now that you mention it, makes sense why the program is printing the first row only, but I don't understand why "res" does not increment at the end of the sentence

Comment: From what I can see, it should be? Have you walked through the code to verify that it's not incrementing with each loop?

Comment: I used Breakpoints and every time a new loop starts, the "res" is equal to 1 again.